# How to Programmatically Replace a Word in a Text Cell with a Button (for popup definitions)

Tags: replacement, button, document-creation

I am attempting to create popup definitions for important words in my lecture notebooks. I plan to create a glossary containing a list of words and their definitions and then search through my lecture notebooks replacing each instance of those words with a button (that has no appearance) which when moused over will display the definition of the word.

I figured out the latter part.  The code below creates an AttachCell[] with a definition that appears and disappears when hovering over the word "domain".  You can try it out if you like.

```
Button[Style["domain", "Text"], 
 obj = AttachCell[EvaluationBox[], 
   Panel[
    Style[
     TextCell[
      "The domain of a function is the set of all possible inputs for \
the function."], Background -> LightGreen], Background -> LightGreen, 
    ImageSize -> {150, Automatic}], Top, 8, Bottom, 
   RemovalConditions -> "MouseExit"], AutoAction -> True, 
 Appearance -> None]
```

I know that I can search through a lecture notebook for the word "domain" in a text cell, so that's not the issue.

This issue I am having is that once I find an instance of the word "domain", I can't seem to figure out how to replace the word with the button above. It seems simple.  I must be missing something very easy.  I tried Paste[] but the button isn't active once pasted.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NotebookWrite` after `NotebookFind` to automatically create an inline cell within a text cell:

```
NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "domain"];
NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], ToBoxes@mybutton]
```